# Is there a `stack run` similar to `cabal run`?

Tags: haskell, stackage

Up until recently, I was executing this *beauty* to build + run a project with stack:

```
stack build && .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-4.1/7.10.3/bin/<project-name>
```

I was told on IRC that this can be simplified to

```
stack build && stack exec <project-name>
```

Can this be simplified even more, to

```
stack run
```

or at least

```
stack run <project-name>
```

?

If I recall correctly this was possible with `cabal run`.

**Edit:**

@haoformayor's comment is getting close:

```
alias b='stack build --fast --ghc-options="-Wall" && stack exec'
```

Although this still needs the project name, right?

I've also started to get close with

```
function stack-run () { stack build && stack exec `basename "$PWD"` }
```

Although this only works if the project name matches with the folder name.  Maybe we can query cabal/stack for the first `executable` entry in the .cabal file? Or Maybe we could do it with `sed`...

Comment: I don't believe there is an equivalent command. I use shell aliases to do something similar. Something like `alias b='stack build --fast --ghc-options="-Wall" && stack exec'`

Comment: @haoformayor This is getting close to what I am looking for. One sec, I'll extend my question a bit.

Comment: it's fairly easy to grab the executable name if you need it: `grep '^executable' *.cabal | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | head -n 1`

Comment: There is also `stack runghc ./src/Main.hs`

Comment: This is an old question, but: there is now a real `stack run` command in the latest release!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had quite a good experience using:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stack-run

---

Edit 2018-04-05: [Relevant stack issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/233).

---

Old answer:

This is what I ended up doing for now.

```
#/usr/bin/env sh

stack build && stack exec `basename "$PWD"` "$@"
```

I've put the following into a file named `stack-run` under my `$PATH`. `~/.local/bin/stack-run` in my case.

Which allows me to

```
$ stack-run
```

in any directory, and even

```
$ stack run
```

Since in almost all of my projects the executable of the project bears the same name as the folder, this works. But I hope to extend it with support for differing names as well.

---

*Edit 2016-09-26:* I've also found this, but haven't given it a try yet:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stack-run

Comment: Now stack 1.9.1 has `stack run` !

Answer (score 13):

As it's mentioned here http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html#quick-start-guide, you can use `stack exec my-project-exe` where `my-project-exe` is the name of the executable in your .cabal file.

Comment: it's also possible to pass some command line arguments: `stack exec -- <project-name> <arg1> <arg2>`

Comment: Well, I am a bit confused by this answer. @Govind How is your answer different than what I mentioned in my question about `stack exec`? I'm looking for a command that would `stack build` + `stack exec` a project, similarly to how I remember `cabal run` doing it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`--exec`](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command.html#other-flags) to tell stack what program should be run after a successful built:

```
stack build --exec <executable-name>
```

You can also specify arguments for the executable, e.g.

```
stack unpack pandoc && cd pandoc*
stack build --exec "pandoc --version"
```

That's probably the closest you'll get compared to `cabal run`, since both `stack exec` and the `--exec` flag need an executable name. The cleanest variant, however, would be an additional `stack-run` command, that does `stack build --exec <first-executable in .cabal>`. It could be worth [a feature request](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues) on the project's GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: By the way, if you have both cabal _and_ stack installed, you could also run `stack build --exec "cabal run"`. But that's somewhat contrived.